# Conditional formatting in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I have a datasheet view that I'm trying to apply some conditional formatting to, where depending on the content of the cell, the cell gets a certain background color (i.e., if the cell reads Critical, the background color turns red). I am unable to do so in Designer, and am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible, because of the datasheet view runs as an ActiveX control, not as HTML, so the customization in datasheet view is not supported, you can't perform any conditional formatting!

Comment: Is this still true ... I'm looking at our SharePoint site, and I'm using Chrome, so I don't think it's an ActiveX control !